# woocommerce edit order before send to clients email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I`m using wordpress with woocommerce.
I can`t find solution how to NOT send automatically email  after purchase order, but admin can edit and add extra shiping cost individualy and then send email.
Thank you everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out! This code put in functions.php file

```
function my_change_status_function ($order_id) {$order = new WC_Order($order_id); return 'on-hold';}
```